# Trying to run Virtualbox under NX session: getting permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, nx

I am running Nomachine NX server on my Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm connecting from a Windows 7 machine using NX client.

When I try to start VirtualBox, I get a permission denied error. The same user that I use to connect to NX session can obviously run VirtualBox just fine.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Run an `strace -Ff virtualbox 2>&1 | grep -i denied` and see what system call is giving the permission denied...

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that local access from the Ubuntu machine was leading to the same error. A restart fixed the problem, though this is the first time I've had to resort to a restart for VirtualBox. allquixotic's response will help next time I face a similar problem.